# NVIDIA X Server Settings only show one huge screen

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, resolution

My current laptop features dual graphics. I am trying to set screen resolution using the NVIDIA X Server Settings application, but it only show one huge screen, which is composed of my external monitor and integrated display, and I can't change the settings from there.

The only way I can rearrange my screen is through Ubuntu's "Displays" settings, but it won't let me pick up a primary display and doesn't work with different display resolutions.

There is a very similar question "Nvidia X Server Settings only shows 1 screen (laptop + external monitor connected)" (can't post more than 2 links with less than 10 rep), but it hasn't been satisfactorily answered.

Below there is a screen-shot of my problem:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHVdu.png]

And here a picture of the desktop when I change the resolution of a monitor (screen-shots didn't illustrate the problem):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIg3R.jpg]

Output of nvidia-settings --version:

nvidia-settings:  version 340.29  (buildmeister@swio-cuda-x64-ubuntu1210-01) 
Fri Aug  1 11:17:08 PDT 2014
  The NVIDIA X Server Settings tool.

This program is used to configure the NVIDIA Linux graphics driver.
  For more detail, please see the nvidia-settings(1) man page.

Copyright (C) 2004 - 2010 NVIDIA Corporation.

Comment: Send a bug report to nvidia ? Does it work with the open source driver ?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) Go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `nvidia-settings --version`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.